# convert categorical values to numeric/float index?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

is there a way in pandas or sklearn to convert categorical values to a unique numeric/float index and be included in the pipeline?  ***have to stick with sklearn 18.1 because that is what is available on server***

```
ex:
c1 | c2
--------
cat1 | 1.0
cat2 | 2.0
cat2 | 2.0
cat3 | 3.0
```

been running into problems with labelEncoder and OneHotEncoder NOT being able to run together in a pipeline and have OHE input string data ...

for applying predictions some of the categorical values are not always present and the model fails because I can't use the handle_unknown="ignore" in the pipeline

hence i had to go with using pandas.get_dummies() to OHE which i don't want to use because of the missing categories

```
# tried

class DataFrameSelector(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, attribute_names):
        self.attribute_names = attribute_names
    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self
    def transform(self, X):
        return X[self.attribute_names].values

cat_pipeline = Pipeline([\
                    ("select", DataFrameSelector(cat_features)),\
                  ("index", LabelEncoder()),\
                  ("ohe", OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown="ignore"))\
                ])

test = cat_pipeline.fit_transform(X_train)
test.shape
```

```
# currently using but fails when applying predictions to new data w/o all the categories that were OHE via pandas.get_dummies()

class DataFrameSelector(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, attribute_names):
        self.attribute_names = attribute_names
    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self
    def transform(self, X):
        return X[self.attribute_names].values


                ("cat", Pipeline([\
                    ("select", DataFrameSelector(cat_ohe))\
                ])),\
```